# How can I access the mnemonic in the mobile copay wallet?

Tags: backup, copay, mnemonic-seed

I was encourage to download copay in my phone so that someone could give me 0.001 BTC. In that process I did not write down the 12 words. Is there a way to access them in the app? Thanks.

Comment: Copay on Android or on iOS?

Comment: it's Android OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to view your mnemonic within the Android App under Settings > Bitcoin Wallet: Personal Wallet > Security: Backup.